# Evaluating the integral of $\cos (\theta )\cos\left[\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2 \tan (\phi )}{b^2}\right)\right]$

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, trigonometry

I am trying to evalute the following integral:

```
Integrate[Cos[θ] Cos[ArcTan[a^2/b^2 Tan[φ]]], {φ, 0, 2π}]
```

**I know that for $a=b$ I should get 0 out of the integral since I would be integrating something of the form $A \cos \phi d\phi$ completely around a circle.**

The issue is that the answer for the equation above is:
$\frac{4 b^2 \cos (\theta ) \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)}{\sqrt{b^4-a^4}}$

Which, if I take the limit $a=b$ like this:

```
Limit[(4 b^2 ArcCos[a^2/b^2] Cos[θ])/Sqrt[-a^4 + b^4], b -> a]
```

Results in $4 \cos \theta$ which is typically not 0.

It seems like the $\arctan$-$\tan$ combination is messing things up, but I am not sure.
Can anybody explain why this happens and how I can get to the correct solution?

[EDIT]

I am already assuming $a>0$, $b>0$ and both $a$ and $b$ to be real.

[EDIT 2]
I only just fully understood what the comment of @b.gatessucks implies: I need to divide the integral in pieces and take care to shift the phase of $\tan$ appropriately.

[EDIT 3]
Physically the meaning of the argument of the $\cos$ looks like this: [image: ellipse with annotation]

Where $\tan \psi = \frac{a^2}{b^2} \tan\phi$. So I know that $\psi$ should run from 0 to 360 deg

Comment: What's happening is that `Simplify@Cos[ArcTan[ Tan[\[Phi]]]]` -> `1/Sqrt[Sec[\[Phi]]^2]` so you have a modulus.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment of @b.gatessucks I have solved the issue by splitting the integral into 3 parts where I shift one part by $\pi$ like this:

$\int_{\frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{3 \pi }{2}} \cos (\theta ) \cos \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2 \tan (\phi )}{b^2}\right)+\pi \right) \, d\phi +\int_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} \cos (\theta ) \cos \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2 \tan (\phi )}{b^2}\right)\right) \, d\phi +\int_{\frac{3 \pi }{2}}^{2 \pi } \cos (\theta ) \cos \left(\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2 \tan (\phi )}{b^2}\right)\right) \, d\phi$

which gives me the answer

$-\frac{i b^2 \sqrt{b^4-a^4} \cos (\theta ) \left(2 \cosh ^{-1}\left(\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)-\log \left(-i \left(\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}+1\right)\right)+\log \left(i \left(1-\frac{a^2}{\sqrt{a^4-b^4}}\right)\right)\right)}{2 |a^4-b^4| }$

Taking the limit of $a=b$ in that case correctly evaluates to 0. (In fact, the integral always evaluates to 0, because I integrate a constant value over a closed curve)

Comment: Please post the *Mathematica*  code for that (as well). Pretty-print is difficult to evaluate.

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is correct (for the original question).  The standard inverse tangent is a function and has a fixed range, normally `-Pi/2` to `Pi/2`.  In that case one has that `Cos[ArcTan[X]]` is greater than or equal to zero for all (real) `X`, including `X = Tan[phi]`.  Unless the integrand is identically zero (except on a set of measure zero), the integral should be a positive multiple of `Cos[theta]`.  Perhaps you want the factor to be `Cos[ArcTan[a^2 Sin[phi], b^2 Cos[phi]]]`, which integrates to zero in agreement with your answer.

Comment: @MichaelE2 no I am sure the phase-shift is the correct thing to do. The reason is that ArcTan[(a/b)^2 Tan[\[Phi]]] represents the angle the interface normal of an ellipse makes with the x-axis as determined from the angle the local x,y coordinates make with the x-axis (this angle is $\phi$). So I know that the whole thing should run from 0 to 360 deg and that the minima and maxima should coincide with those found when a=b. ---- So maybe I didn't explain enough of the background of the problem in my original question, but this is what I was looking for

Comment: That is the alternative I suggested: `ArcTan[a^2 Sin[phi], b^2 Cos[phi]]` equals `ArcTan[a^2 Tan[phi]/ b^2]` plus phase shift, just what you show on the ellipse.  *Mathematica* already has the function you want, and you don't have to break the integral apart.  See the [two versions of ArcTan](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ArcTan.html) in the documentation.

Comment: I had tried it, but it gave a very different result. However, looking at the documentation I found that I should use ArcTan[b^2 Cos[phi]],a^2 Sin[phi]] to get the correct result. Thanks! If you could write it as an answer I will definitely accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I will drop cos(theta) and rename a/b=x. Then you integral has the form:

```
 int = Integrate[ Cos[ArcTan[x^2 Tan[ϕ]]], {ϕ, 0, 2 π}, 
  Assumptions -> x > 0]
```

yielding

```
(4 ArcCosh[x^2])/Sqrt[-1 + x^4]
```

At x=1 one can find a finite limit:

```
Limit[int, x -> 1]
```

equal to 4.
One can also plot it:

```
Plot[int, {x, 0, 2}]
```

returning this plot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of how to get the answer to the integral, but I found out that it was in fact not the answer to the integral that was incorrect, but rather what I fed it: the Cos[ArcTan[ Tan[\[Phi]]]] which has a modulus at $\pi/2$